# Should I use PartialViewResult or separate method in another contoller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP MVC 4 framework. For example, I have 2 controllers: MainPanelController and CartController.

MainPanel controller defines methods and views for showing base main panel functions. Cart controller for example defines standard cart methods: RemoveFromCart, ClearCart, AddItemToCart etc.

Where should I define ShowCartItems method, if I want to display cart items list in main panel index page? I have two choises:

- in CartController as PartialViewResult and render it in Index View of
  MainPanel controller
- completely define it in MainPanelController

I think showing cart items is CartController's task. Or maybe should I define ShowCartItems view in MainPanelController?

Comment: Could you put some code? (Controllers and Views)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what your are looking for is `RenderAction` method, which provides you a way to output an action from other controller:

```
    @{
Html.RenderAction("ShowCartItems","CartController");
}
```

Comment: Yes, `RenderAction` is a void and makes a internal write call, while `Action` returns the string. Have fun! :)